# setting up association for a has_one that is self-referential

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User and a Reviewer table.

Reviewer tracks user_id and reviewer_id

now my association is setup like this:

```
  # reviewer
  has_one :reviewer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviewer
  has_many :active_managements, class_name: 'Reviewer',
                                foreign_key: 'reviewer_id',
                                dependent: :destroy
  has_one :my_reviewer, through: :reviewer, source: :user
```

what I'm trying to set up is that a User can have one reviewer, but can review many.

Now I'm trying to make it so that I can do

```
current_user.my_reviewer.first_name
```

f.ex and get the first name of the reviewer of the current user. However currently the

```
  has_one :my_reviewer, through: :reviewer, source: :user
```

just goes to yourself. Which I think has to do with the source.  If I try to change it to :reviewer I get this error:

```
Could not find the source association(s) :reviewer in model Reviewer. Try 'has_many :my_reviewer, :through => :reviewer, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user or reviewer_user?
```

and if I change it to reviewer_user

I get this error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column reviewers.reviewer_user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ... "users" INNER JOIN "reviewers" ON "users"."id" = "reviewers...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "reviewers" ON "users"."id" = "reviewers"."reviewer_user_id" WHERE "reviewers"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: you need has_many :through i guess

Comment: i do have that just has_one

Comment: @ArupRakshit that only gets the object reviewer

Comment: What the error you are getting when you have `has_one :my_reviewer, through: :reviewer, source: :user`

Comment: none, but it refers to itself (the user_id) and not the (reviewer_id)

Comment: I am not still get what you want. Have you tried `has_one :my_reviewer, through: :reviewer, source: :user, foreign_key: :reviewer_id`.

Comment: gets the same result, which I find strange. Maybe my associations are setup incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewers are Users, right?  So why not just get rid of the reviewer table and do this:

```
# user

has_many :reviewees, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "my_reviewer_id"
belongs_to :my_reviewer, class_name: "User"
```

Comment: you would also have to migrate:  ```rails g migration AddReviewerToUsers my_reviewer_id:integer```